# ROS Answers SE migration: Need Packages

Tags: ros, ros-groovy, packages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

where can i get following packages:

- Eigen
- arm_navigation_msgs

If i try to clone arm navigatin from kforge.ros.org i get an error:

```
hg clone url:/armnavigation/armnavigation armnavigation
```

i had to write url because for me it's not allowed to post links url stands for http : //kforge.ros.org

is kforge.ros.org down?

abort: error: Connection timed out

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/112721/need-packages/) by [Brainjay](https://answers.ros.org/users/10121/brainjay/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2013-12-22

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2013-12-24**:
Is there any reason you cannot install the binary packages? Also, adding information on your OS, version of ROS and what you intent to do might help people answering your question. Also: please know that arm_navigation is sort of EOL in groovy (hydro doesn't have it anymore).

**Comment by [Brainjay](https://answers.ros.org/users/10121/brainjay/) on 2013-12-25**:
I have ubuntu 12.04 LTS and ROS Groovy. If i try to install the armnavigation package i get the error "connection timed out" and i don't know where to get the Eigen package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I assume you have followed the ROS [installation tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/Ubuntu)?

Just to clarify: is there any reason you cannot do `sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-arm-navigation`? And yes, kforge.ros.org is being phased out (if it hasn't been shutdown completely already).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2013-12-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Brainjay](https://answers.ros.org/users/10121/brainjay/) on 2013-12-27**:
ok thanks that helped me. Now i need one more packages named: barett_hand_msgs Do you know where to get it?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2013-12-27**:
No idea; have you tried using things like rosdep?